# Having problems w/ do-while and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem with my code, why when a i started it always send me an error?

```
Import java.util.*;
public class main {
    ArrayList<String> birth = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    public main {
        String input = "", strDay = "", strMonth = "", strYear = "";
        int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
        boolean invalid = true;
        System.out.println("Masukkan tanggal lahir Anda (ddmmyyyy): ");
       
        while (invalid) {
            do {
                input = scn.next();
                
                if (input.length() == "0") {
                    birth.add(input);    
                }

                strDay = input.substring(0, 2);
                strMonth = input.substring(2, 4);
                strYear = input.substring(4, 8);
                    
                day = Integer.parseInt(strDay);
                month = Integer.parseInt(strMonth);
                year = Integer.parseInt(strYear);

                if ((month == 1 && day > 31) || (month == 3 && day > 31) || (month == 5 && day > 31) || (month == 7 && day > 31) || (month == 8 && day > 31) || (month == 10 && day > 31) || (month == 12 && day > 31)) {
                    System.out.println("Hari di bulan " + month + " tidak boleh lebih besar dari " + 31);
                    continue;
                }
                    
                if ((month == 4 && day > 30) || (month == 6 && day > 30) || (month == 9 && day > 30) || (month == 11 && day > 30)) {
                    System.out.println("Hari di bulan " + month + " tidak boleh lebih besar dari " + 30);
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (month == 2 && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) && day > 29) {
                    System.out.println("Hari di bulan " + month + " tahun kabisat tidak boleh lebih besar dari " + 29);
                    continue;
                }
                    
                if (month > 12) {
                    System.out.println("Bulan tidak boleh lebih besar dari " + 13);
                    continue;
                }   

            } while (!input.equals("0"));
            invalid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If i deleted the "do-while" and change to "if" like below in "while (invalid)", but why when i get the array list from "birth", it always output 0?  not the one i input it? (It must be use .equal)

```
if (input.equals("0")) {
   birth.add(input);
   break;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and add some more examples of what input you provide, what you expect to happen and what you get instead (if you get exceptions post the entire stacktraces nicely formatted). Besides that, did you step through your code with a debugger already? And finally there are a few things not needed or unwelcome in SO: "my name is Kevin" - thanks for the info but unnecessary, "Can you help me a soon as possible?" - not likely to improve your odds, just remove that. :)

Comment: One more thing: "it always send me an error" - it would be good if you described _what_ error and _where_ you get it. With non-English messages we'd have to guess what would be considered an "error".

Comment: For one thing, I'd expect `input.length() == "0"` to fail to compile - `String.length()` returns an integer, whereas `"0"` is a string...

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
if (input.length() == "0") {
       birth.add(input);    
}
```

The method `length()` returns an int and you are comparing against a String. Maybe you meant:

```
if (!(input.length() == 0)) {
        birth.add(input);    
}
```

Note the not operator

Comment: Check can be `input.length() != 0` or `input.length() > 0`

Comment: @RobCo Yes it can be. But using the same code is better for pointing the mistake.